# Determine flow rate of side outlet from known flow rate in river

Tags: fluid-dynamics

> **What reading is recommended to determine the initial flow rate of water through an intake from a river**, given known intake diameter, and angle of incidence. I am aware that Bernoulli's equation and Torricelli's law are applicable to determine the flow rate in a connected pipe, however these will not give me a close enough approximation (ie: I am guessing that the angle of intake will have a considerable bearing on actual flow rate, not just the depth of inlet).
>
> *Specifically how do i relate the flow rate of the water through intake point to the flow rate of the river?*

[image]

**1. Background:** Design of low cost water mill for remote location.

**2. Limitations:** No prior access to site or know watershed data. The mill can not be run of river and I need to use an intake *penstock* system.

**3. Prior working:**
Having determined the required power required to perform the desired tasks, I have been trying to determine the maximum power that can be generated in a makeshift pico-watermill.

From Manning's equation (Leopold & Maddock 1953) the flow rate is
$$Q\approx \frac{1}{c}R^{\frac{2}{3}}S^{\frac{1}{2}}A $$

By integration I have approximated the paremeters in general terms of width ($w$) and height ($h$), such that the hydraulic raduis $R$ (for a parabolic river bed) is:

$$R(w,h)=\frac{hw}{3w\sqrt{w^2+16h^2}+\frac{w^2}{12h}[\ln(\sqrt{w^2+16h^2}+4h)-\ln(w)]}$$

The cross sectional area of flow $A$ (for a parabolic river bed) is:

$$A(w,h)=\frac{2}{3}hw$$

And the slope $S$ is just given by topographical map analysis. Despite the limitations I have an estimated flow rate at a given point in the river of $0.42\space m^3s^{-1}$.

I have all the information needed for calculating power except the **new** flow rate ($Q_2$)through the intake as:
$$P=\rho g H Q_2 C_2$$
(Fox, Pritchard & McDonald 2004).

Is there any known references for working out the new flow rate ($Q_2$) through the intake pipe.

Comment: @David Z Bold and highlighted.

Comment: Better to ask how to calculate the flow rate directly, rather than asking for references, but okay.